# Intermittent USB Enumeration

Tags: usb, usb-device

I have a FS USB-powered device I'm working with. We have multiple different devices that all use the same USB circuitry, but for some reason on the latest build (700 pieces) of a particular device we're seeing intermittent USB enumeration failures. If I continually cycle USB power, I can get it to fail about 10% of the time.

Here's an instance of not enumerating:

[image: NoEnum]

And here's a successful enumeration with the exact same device, same cable, PC, etc.:

[image]

I have verified the correct components were used. Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to run signal integrity or CH 9 testing here (though I do have a scope). Here's the relevant circuit; this runs to a STMicro STM32F205 microcontroller.

[image]

Anyone see anything they don't like?

Comment: What does your PCB layout look like? What is your PCB stackup? Have you changed PCB suppliers? Is your PCB supplier aware that you need controlled impedance?

Comment: I should have clarified: this device has been in production for six years, and nothing has chnaged on the layout. We DID recently get a new PCB supplier.

Comment: "nothing has changed" doesn't necessarily mean that your layout is correct - it just means that it worked well enough with whatever stackup and materials your previous PCB supplier used...

Comment: What tool are you using to log the USB activity?

Comment: The problem is not in these parts of the schematic. Show how the USB pins go to MCU. In fact show the whole thing with MCU, and the surroundings of the MCU, how it is powered and how boot pins are handled.

Comment: We need to see the PCB layout, not just the schematic.

Comment: @Scott Seidman - Total Phase Beagle 480

Comment: @Justme - there is nothing else between the USB power circuitry and the micro. I'm not sure what you mean by "how the USB pins go to MCU".

Comment: Do you have anything else on D+ and/or D- before the MCU? Any pull-ups or pull-downs? Anything that might cause the MCU to go to bootloader?

Comment: @Justme - The D+ pin on the MCU has an internal 1.5k pullup. Nothing else outside the MCU.

Comment: Show. Us. The. PCB. Layout. or do you not really want the help ... ?